# blast database index error

Tags: indexing, blast

I got the following err msg when I ran tblastn

tblastn -query ~/seq.fa -out ~/seq.out -db ~/blast/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/db/nr -num_alignments 20000
BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide database [~/blast/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/db/nr] in search path [~/blast/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/bin::/directory/path/to/blast/databases:]

in the /db, there are nr file with phd, phi, phr, pin, pnd, pni, pgo, ppd, ppi, psd, psi and psq extensions for all nr files ranging from 00 to 16 namely, nr.00.phr etc.

If the index files are one of these files that are in db folder, why does blast not find them?

does nr contain representative genome because this is what I want to use?

how about microbial database?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Blast cannot find the nr database because it is looking for files called nr.phd, nr.phi, etc...  If you create a file called `nr.pal` in `~/blast/ncbi-blast-2.2.29+/db/` that contains the following:

```
TITLE nr database
DBLIST  nr.00 nr.01 nr.02 nr.03 nr.04 nr.05 nr.06 nr.07 nr.08 nr.09 nr.10 nr.11 nr.12 nr.13 nr.14 nr.15 nr.16
```

your command should work. Let me know how it goes....good luck, Paul

Comment: thanks Paul......I actually think I should have been using blastp. terrible mistake on my part as blastp works fine.